# Warning when omitting / removing 'strong' attribute from Property?

Tags: ios, properties, xcode5, automatic-ref-counting

Reading [ProgrammingWithObjectiveC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW4), I can say:

> There’s no need to specify the strong attribute explicitly, because it is the default.

If I omit the 'strong' attribute for a property in my project like this,

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *string;
```

it gives me a warning:

> No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed

aka.

> -Wobjc-property-no-attribute

So somehow the compiler seems to be thinking that I´m still doing manual reference counting, otherwise there wouldn´t be any warning.

Also, when creating a new empty project, it doesn´t warn me when there´s no 'strong' attribute, so it must have something to do with the current project settings, maybe even some flag that isn´t reachable via the UI. The project is a rather old one (~2 years) and has undergone several migration steps in the meantime (XCode 3 > 4 > 5, Non-ARC > ARC etc.).

I´ve looked everywhere in the project settings, but somewhere seems to be a missing checkmark or something.

Anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: I did not experience that problem, but in your build log there should be a warning identifier `-Wsomething`. Perhaps that gives some clue. Knowing the warning you can explicitly disable it with the `-Wno-something` compiler flat.

Comment: I don´t want to disable the warning, I wanna know what´s wrong with the compiler. :)

Comment: I understand that (and I don't know where it comes from). My idea was that "name" of the warning might give some hint. Did you find it in the build log?

Comment: It´s -Wobjc-property-no-attribute

Comment: Can you show the concrete property declaration that causes the warning?

Comment: see original post. I added it.

Comment: Did you verify the ARC is not disabled for that particular file?

Answer (score 3):

Just searched for it, and the closest build property would be `CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_ATOMIC_PROPERTIES` which I doubt has any relationship.

You can check which default parameters your target overrides by selecting "All" and "Levels" options in the Build Settings view.

[image]

Check for the warnings that default to No but are being turned into Yes by your target.

Comment: ...but again: I don´t want the warning to be turned off, I wanna fix my project file.

Comment: You only have to "fix" it if you consider it an error. By default Xcode thinks that omitting `strong` is not an error, if you do consider it an error (by enabling that flag), then you simply fix it by adding `strong` where it's missing. Otherwise you clear the flag and there's nothing to fix as you no longer consider it an error.

Comment: I didn´t enable a warning flag that enables this warning. As you also noticed, -W objc-property-no-attribute seems to be not adjustable via the Xcode UI. I also didn´t fumble around in any other build related scripts to enable this warning. "grep -R objc-property-no-attribute *" shows no output when run in my project root.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of Xcode. This is a new compiler feature and how it works has changed several times in recent updates.

Make sure your project is configured to use clang/llvm and not gcc. I can't remember if gcc supports ARC at all (can someone comment of they do know?) but it definitely doesn't support all the features. And an old Xcode project will be using gcc unless you changed it. All recent language changes are only implemented in clang/llvm

Do you have ARC enabled? That will change the behaviour as we'll beware ARC can be enabled or disabled project wide or for specific files.

Some changes in Xcode only apply to new projects, and old projects have are configured to disable them. Have a look over the settings for anything related to ARC that is not set to the default value.

Comment: I confirm that before Xcode 4.3 the default for @property was weak/assign (I don't remember exactly which). The behavior changed in Xcode 4.3 to be the same as local variables (always __strong by default)

Comment: "Some changes in Xcode only apply to new projects, and old projects have are configured to disable them. Have a look over the settings for anything related to ARC that is not set to the default value." < I´m exactly looking for this configuration settings, that apply to new projects but not to old migrated ones. And yes: I´m running Xcode 5.1, using LLVM, ARC is on project-wide, everything ARC-related is set to the defaults (i.e. not shown in bold font).

Comment: @sdk just to be sure, did you check `Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources` to verify the file doesn't have `-fno-objc-arc`?

Comment: Jep, I did check that.